# Why don't I see my IP address?

Tags: networking, 18.04, network-manager, ip

[image]

I looked up few sites to know how to check my ip address and they asked me to  open network panel and then open th wheel button and look up the address mention against ipv4.. but I don't see any ipv4 there..
I ran `ip a` on terminal and I don't know where to look up my ip address...
Actually I've hosted something (mycroft-core) on my laptop which will be accessed by an android app by entering the IP address of my laptop... What should I do now?

Comment: you can find it from your browser: https://whatismyipaddress.com/ip-lookup

Comment: Have you plugged in any wired connection? This dialog is expected when you click on gear icon next to "Network -> Wired -> **Cable Unplugged**". Which IP address are trying to find, public or private? It seems you are connected wifi and trying to get IP address of Wired connection.

Comment: Actually I've hosted something (mycroft-core) on my laptop which will be accessed by an android app by entering the IP address of my laptop... What should I do now?

Answer (score 6):

From your attached screenshot it seems that you are currently connected to WiFi and trying to get IP details of a **Wired Connection**. The dialog in screenshot has not listed IP details because you aren't connected to any **wired** connection but a wireless connection thus no IP is assigned in wired connection and lists only "Hardware Details" and "Last Usage" and that's quite obvious.

I assume that you are trying to get details of local IP, a.k.a. LAN IP. To get IP details of that:

- Go to ***Settings→Wi-Fi*** and click on gear icon (⚙) next to the network name (SSID) of which you are trying to get IP details.
- Or, for IPv4, open a terminal and run

  ```
  hostname -I | awk '{print $1}'
  ```

Comment: Actually I've hosted something (mycroft-core) on my laptop which will be accessed by an android app by entering the IP address of my laptop... What should I do now?

Comment: @SiddharthPandey Are your android phone and laptop connected to same wifi? You need to get IP details of laptop which I have already described in my answer.

Comment: No they are on different data connections. I've tried it earlier by both being on the same network but it couldn't connect.. Probably nothing to do with IP address then!  So I just need the IPv4 right?

Comment: @SiddharthPandey May be. Can't comment on the actual issue. Generally ipv4 is sufficient. If they are on different network try using public IP which can be obtained from https://www.whatismyip.com/ but that would be slow and unreliable. I'll not recommend using Public IP unless mobile is "very far" from laptop.

Comment: @SiddharthPandey If they are on different connections there could be a NAT or a firewall preventing direct connections. You can avoid the NAT by using IPv6 (assuming both connections support it).